# Зачем ставить (void) перед printf и другими функциями?

Tags: c

Изучаю С на примере репозитория: https://github.com/ankushagarwal/nweb/blob/master/nweb23.c
И собственно вопрос - зачем ставить `(void)` перед `printf` и другими функциями?

```
(void)sprintf(...);
```

Comment: Вопросы должны включать код примера. А то через полгода репозиторий грохнут и будет непонятно в чем суть вопроса.

Comment: @Kromster код примера в заголовке вопроса)))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Функция `printf` не является `void`-функцией. Она возвращает в вызывающий код значение типа `int`. Таким способом - приведением возвращенного значения к типу `void` - автор кода дает понять компилятору (и читателю кода) то, что возвращаемое значение функции `printf` было проигнорировано им *намеренно*.

Для некоторых функций игнорирование возвращаемого ими значения является нормальной ситуацией (например, `printf` или `strcpy`). Для других функций игнорирование их возвращаемого значения обычно свидетельствует о грубой ошибке в коде (например, `malloc` или `fopen`). Многие компиляторы предоставляют [нестандарные] средства для пометки функций как принадлежащих первой или второй группе. Если проигнорировать возвращаемое значение функции второй группы, то компилятор выдаст [нестандарное] диагностическое сообщение.

Однако в некоторых группах разработчиков можно встретить "драконовскую" установку на то, что возвращаемые значения функций *никогда* нельзя просто неявно игнорировать (и компилятор конфигурируется на безусловную выдачу диагностических сообщений в таких случаях). Это довольно бессмысленное требование, но тем не менее оно встречается. И в такой ситуации, чтобы избавиться от диагностики, разработчику приходится вот таким способом *явно* сообщать компилятору, что значение проигнорировано намеренно.